# AMD Omega drivers don't work with kernel 3.17.6 on Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, fglrx

I just installed new fglrx drivers on Ubuntu 14.04. New AMD drivers are distribution-specific, so downloaded them. Since it says they re compatible with kernel up to 3.17 version on [release notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalystOmegaLINReleaseNotes.aspx), downloaded kernel 3.17.6 version and `dpkg -i`'ed it. While installing, there it says there is errors. This is the log.

So, restart computer and after log in, computer freezes. Lucky thing i can reboot, access recovery mode and select between kernels (default version on trusty is 3.13.*).

Then, I tried installing a kernel "between" 3.13 and 3.17; installed 3.15.10 and everything went fine. Tried then 3.17.0 (stable), wrong again. So I stayed on 3.16.7 and everything fine.

Anyone knows what happened with 3.17 and how to solve it? I suspect AMD meant 3.16 on release notes instead 3.16... oh, almost forgot. Here is the log of error when dpkg kernel. Is a fglrx log, same for any 3.17.*:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-core-14.501 for kernel 3.17.4-031704-generic (x86_64)
dom dic 21 03:55:11 CLST 2014
/usr/sbin/dkms: línea 73: cd: /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/14.501/build: No existe el archivo o el directorio
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/3.17.4-031704-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.4-031704-generic»
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6396:12: warning: ‘KCL_fpu_save_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int KCL_fpu_save_init(struct task_struct *tsk)
            ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c: In function ‘KCL_ACPI_Slot_No_Hotplug’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c:845:21: error: ‘struct acpi_device_flags’ has no member named ‘no_hotplug’
          tdev->flags.no_hotplug = true;
                     ^
make[2 ]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o] Error 1
make[1 ]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/14.501/build/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1 ]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.4-031704-generic»
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a patch for fglrx 14.501 to make it working with the kernel 3.17.X ([source](https://gist.github.com/aginor/4f232d4c28aef7685282#file-amd-fglrx-3-17-patch)). Since I wanted to install from debs I did it a bit different way, than described in the linked source.

1. Download deb packages from AMD site
2. Extract the fglrx_core
   `dpkg-deb -R packagename.deb tmp`
3. Apply patch to file
   `tmp/usr/src/fglrx-core-14.501/kcl_acpi.c`
   (I have just added the missing lines manually)
4. Rename/remove old deb package
5. Rebuild package `dpkg-deb -b tmp packagename.deb`
6. Install from fixed deb

Comment: I didn't noticed your answer, I'm gonna check this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

AMD only support up to Kernel 3.16. No support for Kernel 3.17 and > yet

Comment: Omega Driver's Install notes says: "up to 3.17", after that kernel desnt'n work.
No support Sorry :(